# Dynamic table with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 application. I have a screen as ,[image: Customers & Products]

```
           |  Product 1 Product 2   Product 3  ............. Product N
----------------------------------------------------
Customer 1 |     2         1            4
Customer 2 |     3         2            3
Customer 3 |     4         3            2
  .
  .
  .
Customer N
```

here, the column header(Products) is dynamic one and customers also dynamic one
I want to display my screen as like this and my json data would be:

```
    data: [{
    ProductName:"Prod1",
    Data: [{
             CustomerName:"AAA",
             CustomerId:1,
             Count:2
        },
        {
             CustomerName:"BBB",
             CustomerId:2,
             Count:3
        }]
    },
{
    ProductName:"Prod1",
    Data: [{
             CustomerName:"AAA",
             CustomerId:1,
             Count:2
        },
        {
             CustomerName:"BBB",
             CustomerId:2,
             Count:3
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: Are you having issues or are you wanting to know how you could do this?

Comment: I just want a some idea on this how i can do this in Angular 2 and what is the best way to pass the json object.,

Comment: That's not a real question. Review the material in the [help], not to mention the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/)?

Here is some code:

- settings of your columns

your-component.ts:

```
settings = {
    actions: false,
    hideSubHeader: true,
    columns: {
      Customers : {
        title: 'Customers',
        type: 'string'
      },
      Prod1: {
        title: 'Name of your product1',
        type: 'number'
      },
      Prod2: {
        title: 'Name of your product2',
        type: 'string'
      },
      // and so on for all your product
    }
  };
```

- Then you'll have to format your data you want to pass to the smart table in this way:

data

```
data = [{customers = 'AA', Prod1 = 2, Prod2 = 1, ...., ProdN = nbOfProdN }, {customers = 'BB', ....}, ....];
```

- link your data to the table:

For this you'll need to use `LocalDataSource` from ng2-smart-table in this way:
`yourdatasource.load(data)`

In fact the documentation of [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/) is quite complete and their is a lot more that you can do with this tool.

Comment: Thanks for your input.